# How to do port forwarding from host(Mac) to virtual machine (Linux) running on VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to forward two ports (Oracle db and Tomcat server) with following settings on VirtualBox's port forwarding option;
[image]

[image]

IP Address of my virtual machine: 10.0.2.15.

I am not able to load tomcat server on my virual machine with the above settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is `127.0.0.1` as Host IP intentional? that allows only connections coming from your Host to talk to the Guest.

On the other hand if you set the Host IP is to nothing - it is equivalent to saying `0.0.0.0`
It means that any system that can access your Host on TCP port 1521/8080 will be able to talk to the Guest.